# How do I stop all handlers running in the background?

Tags: java, android-handler

I'm writing an application that is creating audio players dynamically. By pressing a button, I want all handlers to stop and start again when I call them. The handlers, basically, are responsible for updating the seek-bar of the audio player. the seek-bar and the play button are being creating into a linearlayout, and this linear layout is being adding into a parent linearlayout. this way, for example, if I decide by code to create 4 audio players and I want them to be able to play the audio together, I put in a loop the creation of a 4 linearlayouts and add them to the parent linearlayout. the code more or less looks like this (this is just the relevant part, not the real code...):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    LinearLayout audioLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    audioLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    audioLayout.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    final Button btnAudioPlay = new Button(this);
    btnAudioPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams playButtonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    playButtonParams.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
    audioLayout.addView(btnAudioPlay, playButtonParams);
    final SeekBar sbAudioPosition = new SeekBar(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams seekbarParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    seekbarParams.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0);
    audioLayout.addView(sbAudioPosition, seekbarParams);
    parentLayout.addView(audioLayout);

    final MediaPlayer mpAudio = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(audFile));
    mpAudio.setLooping(false);
    mpAudio.seekTo(0);
    int totalTime = mpAudio.getDuration();
    sbAudioPosition.setMax(totalTime);
    sbAudioPosition.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
            if (fromUser)
            {
                mpAudio.seekTo(progress);
                sbAudioPosition.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    });

    mpAudio.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            btnAudioPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            sbAudioPosition.setProgress(0);
        }
    });

    btnAudioPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!mpAudio.isPlaying()) {
                mpAudio.start();
                btnAudioPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sbAudioPosition.setMax((int) mpAudio.getDuration());
                        int currentPossition = mpAudio.getCurrentPosition();
                        sbAudioPosition.setProgress(currentPossition);
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                mpAudio.pause();
                btnAudioPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I press a button, I'm updating the view, and I want all handlers to stop, but it doesn't happening... I tried to declare, before the onCreate the Handler handler = null; (instead of the final handler) and then in the linearlayout make it new and it worked, but in the method of the button I called handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); and it didn't work. I tried to declare the runable as well and call handler.removeCallbacks(runOnUiThread);, but my application crashes... :(

What do I need to do to solve it?
If I want that one audio play will stop the current audio playing, is it possible? will it solve my problem?

Sorry for the length and thanks for the helpers. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Handler` as a member of your `Activity` something like:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sbAudioPosition.setMax((int) mpAudio.getDuration());
                    int currentPossition = mpAudio.getCurrentPosition();
                    sbAudioPosition.setProgress(currentPossition);
                    mHandler.post(this);
                }
            };
```

Then use the `mHandler` when you make execute `mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,delay)`. And then you can call `mHandler.removeCallbacks(null);` when you want to remove them all.

**Note**: You can remove specific runnables like this: `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);`